# Difference between "that's not you" and "you're not you"

Tags: that

My understanding is "you're not you" means "you're not yourself", while "that's not you" is something I would use for example if we were looking at a photo. Is that right? Can you explain why "that" changes the meaning of the sentence? Is it because "that" is a "demonstrative pronoun"? What other situations would you use the one or the other?

Comment: I cannot think of any situation where I would use "you're not you", except in science fiction (or perhaps philosophy). I see it's also a title of a novel and a  film. And it was used in a Snickers campaign in the same sense.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They are quite different.

**"That is not you"** is a straightforward grammatical form. "That" can be something you are looking at e.g. a photo, or a reference to some characteristic. If I say "I think I'll take a course in homeopathy" my wife, would probably say "That's not you".

***"You're not you"*** is an idiomatic way of telling a person that they are behaving out of character, or that they look ill. But perhaps more common, and closely related is ***"you don't seem yourself"***. Or indeed a person might say ***"I don't feel myself"***, usually meaning that they don't feel well.